# Get public Next JS env variables inside browser debugger in production

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I am trying to figure out why my build environment is not loading the correct environment variables.

Can you access the NEXT_PUBLIC environment variables through the browser?

Where would that be stored?

If I open dev tools and type `debugger` my understanding is that it should be there somewhere but I am not sure where to find it.

[image: debugger]

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a variable called process?

Environment variables are in scoped in process.env object:

process: {
env: {
...public variables
}
}